# Ruby: use aws-sdk to list s3 objects with marker and max-keys

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I found there has no good example in aws-sdk document to list s3 objects with marker and max-keys options.

In Java, I can do it by  :

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
.withBucketName(bucket)
.withPrefix(s3Prefix)
.withMarker(s3Marker)
.withMaxKeys(40));
```

but in ruby, I can only find the with_prefix method but no way to fill other options. please help to tell how to config to list the objects with marker or max-kays

Answer (score 4):

It took me a while to figure this out, for the same reasons: no good examples in the documents.

Here is how I managed to get it working, however:

```
items = bucket.objects.with_prefix(prefix).page(:next_token => { :marker => marker }, :per_page => 100)
items.each do |item|
    puts item.key
end
```

items is a [PageResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html#!AWS/Core/PageResult.html) object.

I eventually figured out using a combination of the aws docs and reading the source code.

Comment: Important note: This will only return one page (in your case 100 keys), you might need to repeat that process using the .more? method and use the next_page method to iterate through all the objects.